# React Native Navigation : Child components are not rendered on screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I followed the documentation [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigation) and wrote this code.

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import {createAppContainer, createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import LoginScreen from "./src/components/LoginScreen";


export default App = () => createAppContainer(createStackNavigator({
    Login: {screen: LoginScreen},
}));
```

**LoginScreen.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text, Button} from 'react-native';

export default class LoginScreen extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'Login',
    };

    render() {
        const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
        return (
            <View style={this.styles.viewStyle}>
                <Text> Login </Text>
                <Button
                    title="Go to Jane's profile"
                    onPress={() => navigate('Home', {name: 'Jane'})}
                />
            </View>

        );
    }
}
```

**Output**

A blank screen. Login page is not rendered on screen.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to export a method in your `App.js`

Either Import and use it as a method or change your default export to

```
export default App = createAppContainer(createStackNavigator({
    Login: {screen: LoginScreen},
}));
```